# Flutter convert JSON stream List into Map object

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am attempting to convert the JSON results of a Google Places API call to fit my Restaurant object, however, being new to Flutter I seem to be having issues. My results are put into a List but as you can see my Restaurant class expects a Map.

Here is my Restaurant class

```
class Restaurant{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final GeoPoint location;
  final String image;

  const Restaurant({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.location,
    this.image,
  });

  Restaurant.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String id)
    : this(
        id: id,
        name: data['name'],
        location: data['location'],
        image: data['image'],
  );

}
```

The relevant part of my body:

```
Expanded(
              child: new FutureBuilder(
                future: _updateRestaurantsNearby(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
                      snapshot.hasData == null) {
                    return Container();
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return _buildLoadingIndicator();
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new RestaurantCard(
                        restaurant: Restaurant.fromMap(
                            snapshot.data[index], snapshot.data[index].id),
                      );
```

And finally my class for handling JSON data. I am using the google_maps_webservice package:

```
Future _updateRestaurantsNearby() async {
    PlacesSearchResponse response = await places.searchNearbyWithRadius(
      new Location(lat, long),
      radius,
    );

    if (response.hasNoResults) {
      print("No results");
      return null;
    }

    var nearbyRestaurants;
    var results = response.results;

    results.forEach((f) {
      Restaurant restaurant = Restaurant(
          id: f.id,
          name: f.name,
          location: GeoPoint(f.geometry.location.lat, f.geometry.location.lng),
          image: null);
      nearbyRestaurants.update(restaurant);
      //print(nearbyRestaurants.length);
    });
    return nearbyRestaurants;
  }
```

I would like to convert the data in the loop above to a Map instead of as a List so I can use them in the ListView builder, just not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Could you post some sample JSON and an example of what you want to have done with it?

Comment: var results will be a List of PlaceSearchResult objects because of the package I'm using but the JSON data looks like this https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#find-place-responses I would like to assign this place data to my Restaurant object since it expects a Map but it's currently a List

Comment: Why not return a list of Restaurants?

Comment: Well for one performance-wise Map is faster to look up data than a List

Comment: Not really. An indexing operation for both a list and a map is an O(1) operation, so they are quite comparable in terms of performance. If anything, a list will be faster, as it's just an address lookup whereas a map needs to run a hashing function on the key first. But that's a pedantic argument anyway since both of them are going to complete in a matter of microseconds if not nanoseconds. So unless you are working with a collection of tens to hundreds of thousands of items, this is a micro-optimization that will ultimately be a waste of time.

Comment: And why are you trying to convert the list to a map anyway? You say you want to use the results in a `ListView.builder`, but that needs a list, not a map.

Answer (score 0):

If the response by the http request returns a valid format, you can cast `as Map<String, dynamic>` on the value that you're passing on `Restaurant.fromMap()`. This lets the method know the data type that's being passed so it can be parsed.

```dart
Restaurant.fromMap(snapshot.data[index] as Map<String, dynamic>, 
    snapshot.data[index].id)
```

Answer (score 0):

in class handle json you can try

```
import 'dart:convert';
Future<List<Model>> callSomething() async {
  /// you handle
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("uri"),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    // convert reponse body to json
    List<dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
    // convert json to objects model
    List<Model> data =
        body.map((dynamic item) => Model.fromJson(item)).toList();
    return data;
  } else {
    throw Exception("Faid to load data");
  }
}
```

you should use [Cusom model in dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) for Model
and if will return for you Objects Model, after use

```
FutureBuilder(future:callSomething(),
...
)
```

goodluck!